# _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse) Error

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, pointers, sdl

I been working in a new project but I encounter with a problem which I can't see why fail.

When I perfom this line delete textY give me the error _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse). So what am I doing wrong?

This is the source code:

**Text.h**

```
 #ifndef TEXT_H
 #define TEXT_H

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Font>  FontPtr;

class Text
{
public:

    Text(FontPtr font, char *text)
    {
        str = new char[35];
        this->font = font;    str = text; 
    }

    Text(const Text& cSource);
    Text& operator=(const Text& cSource);

    ~Text();
    .
    .
    .
    .

private:
    FontPtr font;
    char *str;
    GLuint texture;
    GLfloat pos_x, pos_y, width, height;
};

 #endif
```

**Text.cpp**

```
Text::Text(const Text& cSource)
{
    font = cSource.font;
    texture = cSource.texture;
    pos_x = cSource.pos_x;
    pos_y = cSource.pos_y;
    width = cSource.width;
    height = cSource.height;

    int sizeString = 35;
    if (cSource.str)
    {
        str = new char[sizeString];
        strncpy(str, cSource.str, sizeString);
    }

    else 
    {
        str = 0;
    }
}

Text& Text::operator=(const Text& cSource)
{
    delete[] str;

    font = cSource.font;
    texture = cSource.texture;
    pos_x = cSource.pos_x;
    pos_y = cSource.pos_y;
    width = cSource.width;
    height = cSource.height;

    int sizeString = 35;
    if (cSource.str)
    {
        str = new char[sizeString];
        strncpy(str, cSource.str, sizeString);
    }

    else 
    {
        str = 0;
    }

    return *this;
}

Text::~Text()
{
    delete[] str;
}
```

**Font.h**

```
#ifndef FONT_H
#define FONT_H

class Font
{
public:

    Font(TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color)
    {
        this->font = font;    this->color = color; 
    }

    ~Font();
    .
    .
    .

private:
    TTF_Font *font;
    SDL_Color color;

};

#endif
```

**Font.cpp**

```
Font::~Font()
{
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
}
```

**CGameApplication.cpp**

```
.
.
.
.
void CGameApplication::initializeApplicationFonts()
{
    TTF_Font* font;
    SDL_Color color;

    font = TTF_OpenFont("test.ttf", 15);

    color.r = color.g = color.b = 255;

    GApp->addFont(font, color);

    Text *text = new Text(GApp->getFonts().at(0), " ");
    text->setTexture( CTextM->textToGLTexture(GApp->getFonts().at(0), text) );
    text->setPosX(20);  text->setPosY(20);

    GApp->addText(new Text(*text));

    Text *textY = new Text(GApp->getFonts().at(0), " ");
    textY->setTexture( CTextM->textToGLTexture(GApp->getFonts().at(0), textY) );
    textY->setPosX(80);  textY->setPosY(20);

    GApp->addText(new Text(*textY));
    delete textY;                 //-----> This line crashes the program with that error
}
.
.
.
```

**GameApp.h**

```
#ifndef GAMEAPP_H
#define GAMEAPP_H


class GameApp
{
public:
    GameApp(){
    }

    //~GameApp();

    void addFont(TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color) { 
        vFonts.push_back(FontPtr( new Font(font, color) ) ); }

    vector<FontPtr> getFonts() { return vFonts; }

    void addText(Text *text) { 
        vTexts.push_back(new Text(*text));}

private:
    SDL_Surface *gameMainSurface;
    vector<Image*> vImages; 
    std::vector<FontPtr> vFonts;
    vector<Text*> vTexts;
    vector<Tile*> vTiles;
    Map *currentMap;
};

#endif
```

So I think the problem is that when I destroy the object textY, the pointer to the TTF_Font is destroyed. But I'm not sure because when I add a object Text in the vector I use a copy-constructor so the different pointers got copy without problems.

Comment: Did you walk up the call stack to see which was the last call in your code that caused the debugging failure? (Also, Raw Pointers in STL containers! My eyes! :) )

Comment: Yes, it's only a test while I implement smart pointers in all the STL containers. I going to check the call stack. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get \_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) and/or is\_block\_type\_valid(header->\_block\_use) assertions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418624/why-do-i-get-crtisvalidheappointerblock-and-or-is-block-type-validheader-b)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a `std::string`. That error means that you double deleted something, or something like that, a problem that you wouldn't have if you didn't manage your own memory. Your code is littered with memory leaks and other bugs that you won't have with `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed all the char* for std::string and work without problem. And expected it's not problem if I ask, if there is a problem in use raw pointers in STL containers, I was thinking in use auto_ptr in some of them, and shared_ptr in other objects that it's needed, it is really neccesary?

Comment: @oscar.rpr: You can't use `auto_ptr` in Standard containers. This problem will be fixed in C++11, but in C++03, you will have to use `shared_ptr`- even if there's only ever one reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so I will use shared_ptr instead of raw pointers in STL containers.

Comment: "a problem that you wouldn't have if you didn't manage your own memory" i hate this sentiment in a world of garbage collectors and reference counting that is more difficult to debug. sure string is a special case, but the right answer here is "a problem that you wouldn't have if you managed your memory properly".

Comment: @jheriko: There's a world of difference between garbage collectors and reference counting, and std::string/std::vector. Don't manage your own memory manually. That's just going to lead to infinity bugs.

Comment: yeah, std::string is a good thing for not having to manage character buffers. i don't mean to lump all these things together - std::string (and other things like vector) are not automatic memory management, but reusable code that 'just' gets it right.

Answer (score 10):

From what I can see, the error has to do with the default ctor for `Text`. You take in a `char*` pointer, allocate space for the string, but don't actually copy the `text` into `str`, but simply assign the pointer! You do it correct in the copy ctor though. Now, consider this example:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(char* text){
        str = text;
    }

    ~Foo(){
        delete str;
    }

private:
    char* str;
};

int main(){
    Foo f("hi");
}
```

C++03 (for backwards compatability...) allows literal strings (`"hi"`) to bind to non-const `char*` pointers, as seen in this code. C++11 thankfully fixed that and this should actually no longer compile. Now, deleting a literal string obviously doesn't work, as the string is placed in the read-only section of the .exe and as such isn't `delete`able. I guess this is where your error comes from, if you instantiate a `Text` object from a literal string.

Note that this also happens if you create it from a `char[]` created on the stack:

```
char text[] = "hi";
Foo f(text);
```

as the `Foo` will now try to `delete` a stack-object.

Another case where this might happen is if you double-delete an object:

```
char* text = new char[3];
Foo f(text);
delete text;
```

Comment: Thanks, I already solved the problem changing every char * to std::string, because it's was causing a memory leak and other problems.