# The handle class in C++

Tags: c++

i write a handle class using C++. But when i run my code, i met an error.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class BaseItem{
public:
    virtual BaseItem* clone()
    {
        return new BaseItem(*this);
    }
    virtual void sayHello()
    {
        cout<<"Hello, I am class BaseItem!"<<endl;
    }
};

class ChildItem:public BaseItem{
public:
    ChildItem* clone()
    {
        return new ChildItem(*this);
    }
    void sayHello(){
        cout<<"Hello, I am class ChildItem!"<<endl;
    }
};


template <typename T>
class Handle
{
public:
    Handle():baseItem(NULL), refCount(new size_t(0)) {}
    Handle(T& object):baseItem(object.clone()), refCount(new size_t(1)) {}

    Handle(const Handle<T>& other):baseItem(other.baseItem), refCount(new size_t(1)) {}

    Handle& operator= (const Handle<T>& other)
    {
        ++*other.refCount;
        dec_count();
        baseItem = other.baseItem;
        refCount = other.refCount;
        return *this;
    }

    const T* operator->() const {return baseItem;};
    const T& operator*() const {return *baseItem;};

    T* operator->() {return baseItem;};
    T& operator*() {return *baseItem;};

    virtual ~Handle(void)
    {
        dec_count();
    }
private:
    T *baseItem;
    std::size_t* refCount;
    void dec_count()
    {
        if (-- *refCount == 0 && baseItem != NULL)
        {
            delete baseItem;
            delete refCount;
        }
    }
};
```

This is the main function :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BaseItem item1;
    ChildItem item2;

    vector<Handle<BaseItem> > vec;
    vec.push_back(Handle<BaseItem>(item1));
    vec.push_back(Handle<BaseItem>(item2));

    //for (vector<Handle<BaseItem> >::iterator iter = vec.begin();
    //  iter != vec.end(); iter++)
    //{
    //  
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

when i run the code, the code crashed. i have no idea to debug the code.
This is the error:
[image]

Comment: Any information about the error?

Comment: what error did you "meet"

Comment: And you should really run your program in a debugger, look at the call stack and variable values. If nothing else, edit your question to include the call stack.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg are you sure? I think it is possible to vary the return type as long as it is a subtype

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Regarding the overrides: covariant return types on virtual functions are explicitly allowed by the standard, so from this point of view, the code is valid.

Comment: And now it's kind of a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397545/block-type-is-valid-phead-nblockuse-error You delete something twice, it would seem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Handle's copy c-tor is invalid. It should be like this:

```
Handle(const Handle<T>& other)
  : baseItem(other.baseItem),
    refCount(other.refCount)
{
    ++*refCount;
}
```

http://ideone.com/DB7L9p

Answer (score 1):

The problems I can see are:

- The copy constructor should share and increase the reference count, rather than create a new one;
- The base class needs a virtual destructor.

The first issue causes a double deletion after copying the handle into the vector. Both copies think they are the only reference to the object and hence both try to delete it. This is probably the cause of the crash.

After fixing those, your code appears to run correctly. If you still have problems, I suggest stepping through your failing test case with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Reference count should be a part of actual object rather than part of **Handle**. **Handle** should only increment & decrement the reference count & it should create once.

```
template <typename T>
class RefCounted
{
    public:
        std::size_t refCount;
};

class BaseItem : public RefCounted<BaseItem> {
```

So all classes which is being usable with **Handle** shall be derived from RefCounted.

```
template <typename T> class Handle
{
public:
    Handle():baseItem(NULL) {}
    Handle(T& object):baseItem(object.clone())) {++ other.refCount;}

    Handle(const Handle<T>& other):baseItem(other.baseItem) { ++ other.refCount; }

    Handle& operator= (const Handle<T>& other)
    {
        ++ other.refCount;
        baseItem = other.baseItem;
        return *this;
    }

    const T* operator->() const {return baseItem;};
    const T& operator*() const {return *baseItem;};

    T* operator->() {return baseItem;};
    T& operator*() {return *baseItem;};

    virtual ~Handle(void)
    {
        if (baseItem != NULL && -- (baseItem->refCount) == 0)
        {
            delete baseItem;
        }

    }
private:
    T *baseItem;

};
```

(Disclaimer: It is not a working code, just attempted to explain the concept)

If you are looking for better implementation, Refer http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WTF/wtf/RefCounted.h